# oracle local partition index

Tags: oracle, index

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(employee_id NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
 last_name VARCHAR2(10), 
 department_id NUMBER(2))
PARTITION BY RANGE (department_id)
(PARTITION employees_part1 VALUES LESS THAN (11) , 
 PARTITION employees_part2 VALUES LESS THAN (21) , 
 PARTITION employees_part3 VALUES LESS THAN (31) );
```

Are these statements the same?

```
CREATE INDEX employees_local_idx ON employees (employee_id) LOCAL;

CREATE INDEX employees_local_idx ON employees (employee_id) LOCAL
(
 PARTITION employees_part1, 
 PARTITION employees_part2, 
 PARTITION employees_part3
)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5010.htm), these are the same:

> If you specify this clause [i.e. LOCAL (...)], then the number of
>   PARTITION clauses must be equal to the number of table partitions, and
>   in the same order. If you omit partition, then Oracle Database
>   generates a name that is consistent with the corresponding table
>   partition.